# Android: Change spinner items without closing the spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I am trying to implement a "More" button for a spinner. Basically I want to show only a few items at first and when the user clicks the last item ("More...") the spinner will change and show all items.

So the feature I need here, is a way to dynamically change spinner items **without** closing the spinner. I've managed to do everything but the last part. Every time I change the items the spinner automatically closes (without losing focus).

The only workaround I thought was to use `mSpinner.performClick()` to immediately open the spinner after it closes. Of course, that's not good enough because I get this quick close-reopen effect. Not cool.

I created a custom spinner class that manages the logic:

```
public class ReservationStatusSpinner extends Spinner {
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // State
    // --------------------------------------------------
    private final String mMoreStatus;

    private OnItemSelectedListener mUserListener;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private boolean mOpenInitiated = false;

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Interfaces
    // --------------------------------------------------
    private interface OnSpinnerEventsListener {
        // Not needed, but may be needed in the future -> void onSpinnerOpened();
        void onSpinnerClosed();
    }
    private OnSpinnerEventsListener mOnSpinnerEventsListener;

    public interface OnStatusSelectedListener {
        void onStatusSelected(String status);
    }
    private OnStatusSelectedListener mOnStatusSelectedListener;

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Construction/Initialization
    // --------------------------------------------------
    public ReservationStatusSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mMoreStatus = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.status_more);
        init();
    }

    public ReservationStatusSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mMoreStatus = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.status_more);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Add listener
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected());

        mOnSpinnerEventsListener = new OnSpinnerEventsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpinnerClosed() {
                filterAndSelect();
            }
        };
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Overridden methods
    // --------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // register that the Spinner was opened so we have a status
        // indicator for the activity(which may lose focus for some other
        // reasons)
        mOpenInitiated = true;
        return super.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        // mSpin is our custom Spinner
        if (mOpenInitiated && hasFocus) {
            performClosedEvent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener l) {
        mUserListener = l;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Private methods
    // --------------------------------------------------
    private static ArrayList<String> getAllStatuses(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        CharSequence[] statusesCSArray = context.getResources().getTextArray(R.array.reservation_status);
        for (CharSequence cs : statusesCSArray)
            items.add(cs.toString());
        return items;
    }

    private void performClosedEvent() {
        mOpenInitiated = false;
        if (mOnSpinnerEventsListener != null) {
            mOnSpinnerEventsListener.onSpinnerClosed();
        }
    }

    private void filterAndSelect() {
        List<String> items = filterStatuses((String)getSelectedItem(), mMoreStatus);
        setItems(items);
        setSelection(0);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Public methods
    // --------------------------------------------------
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        // Find status in adapter
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); ++i) {
            if (mAdapter.getItem(i).equals(status)) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pos != -1)
            setSelection(pos);
    }

    public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public void setOnStatusSelectedListener(OnStatusSelectedListener l) {
        mOnStatusSelectedListener = l;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(items);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    // --------------------------------------------------
    public static ArrayList<String> filterStatuses(String selectedStatus, String moreStatus) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(DataUtilities.filterStatuses(selectedStatus));

        // Add selected status at start
        list.add(0, selectedStatus);

        // Append "More"
        list.add(moreStatus);

        return list;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Custom ItemSelectedListener for ReservationStatusSpinner
    // --------------------------------------------------
    private class OnItemSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        private String mPreviousStatus;
        private boolean mMoreClicked = false;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String more = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.status_more);
            String status = getSelectedItem().toString();

            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
            if (status.equals(more)) {
                items.addAll(getAllStatuses(getContext()));
                items.remove(mMoreStatus);
                setItems(items);
                //setStatus(mPreviousStatus);
                mMoreClicked = true;

                // Reopen spinner (it closes after changing data) (TODO: Fix this)
                ReservationStatusSpinner.this.performClick();
            } else if (!mMoreClicked) {
                filterAndSelect();
            }

            if (!status.equals(more)) {
                if (mUserListener != null)
                    mUserListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);

                if (mOnStatusSelectedListener != null)
                    mOnStatusSelectedListener.onStatusSelected(status);
            }

            mPreviousStatus = status;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            if (mUserListener != null)
                mUserListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

and a custom adapter:

```
public class ImageSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> titles) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, titles);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image_spinner_dropdown, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_icon);
        setIcon(icon, getItem(position));

        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status_text);
        text.setText(DataUtilities.addWhitespacesToStatus(getItem(position)));

        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image_spinner_view, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        // Set icon
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_icon);
        setIcon(icon, getItem(position));

        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return view;
    }

    private void setIcon(ImageView icon, String status) {
        // Make sure there are no whitespaces in status
        status = DataUtilities.removeWhitespaceFromStatus(status);

        // Get the correct image for each status
        icon.setImageResource(DataUtilities.statusToIconResource(status));
    }
}
```

In my Spinner, most of the work is done in the `private class OnItemSelected` at the end of the snippet.

At first I thought the problem was the convert view at my adapter (I wasn't using the convert view pattern at first) but as you can see I'm using it now.

The problem occurs on 2 different devices and my emulator so it's safe to assume that it is not a device specific problem.

Anyone have any ideas or any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom dialog with MultiSelectListview and More button.On click of more button you have to add all elements to Listview and call notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: So there is no way to add/delete items from a spinner dynamically?

Comment: @TheCrafter - For add/delete  you have to add/remove from arraylist and call notifyDataSetChanged() on itemSelected() method.

Comment: I already do that. It updates the adapter dataset indeed, but auto-closes the spinner. I am looking for a way to do that without closing the spinner.

Comment: If you will be using custom dialog i.e. OnClick of Spinner you have to open custom dialog with done button . In that case on click of button you have to close dialog.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. Could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Default Spinner can't simple way to load "More" items. But "More" button has no sense. If you have 30-50 items just load all to Spinner. For 50-150 items use own ListBox/RecyclerView based Spinner. If more 150 items user too hard search necessary one item. In last case useful to add "Search" functionality.
See [MultiSelect Spinner](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner) for ideas.

[image]

Comment: It may not make sense to you but it makes perfect sense to my project manager. I am still looking for a way to make it work with a spinner before examining other options. Thank you for sharing that github project though!

Comment: @TheCrafter, try to suggest own solution for your PM